# Moxtra Meet End Android SDK

Tags: android

I am working on integration of [Moxtra Android sdk](http://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/docs-android-sdk/).

There is a requirement in my app to end meet programatically.
I am unable to find such method for android sdk.
Though my fellow iPhone developer has implemented it.

Is it possible in android to end moxtra meet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new call back event has been added to Moxtra Meet Android SDK. You can find the details under the section "Callback for End Meet" at https://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/docs-android-sdk/#moxtra-meet

```
public void setOnEndMeetListener(OnEndMeetListener listener)
```

Sample Code:

```
MXMeetManager.getInstance().setOnEndMeetListener(new MXMeetManager.OnEndMeetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMeetEnded(String meetID) {
    // add code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Many Thanks Ram for adding this in new Moxtra android sdk.